# How can I express the initial processes by Bacon.js in place of Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, frp, bacon.js

I alway do something like this for initial processes:

```
$.when(dom(), webrtc(), websocket('wss://example.com/'), sleep(3000)).then(load, fail);
```

`dom`, `webrtc`, `websocket`, and `sleep` are Promise objects. This expression is useful to load some parallel processes for initiation.

Now I am wondering how I can express these things by Bacon.js, a way of functional reactive programming.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's perfectly fine to mix and match promises into your BaconJS code. That said, given the abstraction BaconJS has a `fromPromise` method.

Use [`Bacon.fromPromise`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-frompromise):

```
var ready = Bacon.fromPromise($.when(dom(), 
                                     webrtc(),
                                     websocket('wss://example.com/'),
                                     sleep(3000)))

ready.onValue(function(value){
    console.log("All ready");
});
```

Note that the power here is in combining these streams, in the initialization phase - you rarely need this so I'd probably stick to a promise if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, initialisation rarely needs to be called though. I'm just wondering if I can remove dependency to Promise and only use Bacon instead, or not...

Comment: Why though? Having different abstractions, each where appropriate is a good thing :)